# Solaris cc segfaults when compiling rsync on intel platform

Tags: solaris, segmentation-fault

I am trying to compile rsync-3.0.7 on Solaris 5.10 on an Intel chipset.

When running `./configure` I see the following (obviously erroneous lines):

```
checking size of int... 0
checking size of long... 0
checking size of long long... 0
checking size of short... 0
checking size of int16_t... 0
checking size of uint16_t... 0
```

In `config.log` I see the following lines:

```
configure.sh:5448: /tool/sunstudio12.1/bin/cc -xc99=all -o conftest -g -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   conftest.c  >&5
"conftest.c", line 123: warning: statement not reached
cc: Fatal error in cc : Segmentation Fault
configure.sh:5448: $? = 1
configure.sh: program exited with status 1
```

Segmentation fault? What could be causing a simple test script to segfault during compilation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wont fix your compiling issues, but you could always look at using the opencsw repo http://opencsw.org/ they have this version of rsync already compiled and have a useful app called pkg-get for performing the installations

Comment: Good answer. To be honest I'm just recording what problems I've had and how I solved them on here because not only do I think I'll come across this again but I'm sure other people will too.

Answer (score 0):

The option `-xc99=all` was causing the segfault. A description of the option can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5265/bjate/index.html) which states that the default is `-xc99=all,no_lib` (which doesn't cause the compiler to segfault).

To make the `configure` script work I edited `configure.sh` it and replaced the instance of `-xc99=all` to `-xc99=all,no_lib`

Answered my own question so that others that encounter this issue may have a vector to try in establishing a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, but couldn't use the `-xc99=all,no_lib` workaround (the program I was building needed all c99 features) and tried manually running the cc command under truss. It showed the segfault happened just after trying to open `/lib/values-xpg6.o`. This file wasn't present, but is available in the `SUNWarc` package. I installed that and the segfault went away.

I'm not entirely sure what the root cause was, but that should help anyone for whom the above workaround fails.