# Problems compiling coreutils-8.5 on Solaris 5.10 on Intel platform

Tags: solaris, coreutils

I am having trouble compiling coreutils-8.5 on Solaris 5.10 on the Intel platform using `cc`.

Firstly I had the following error during `./configure`:

```
checking whether <wchar.h> uses 'inline' correctly... no
configure: error: <wchar.h> cannot be used with this compiler (/tool/sunstudio12.1/bin/cc -xc99=all -g  -D_REENTRANT).
```

This seemed similar to the problem in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/150023/solaris-cc-segfaults-when-compiling-rsync-on-intel-platform). The solution was to edit `configure` and replace the reference of `-xc99=all` to `-xc99=all,no_lib`.

This permitted the configure to complete.

Then I ran `/usr/sfw/bin/gmake` and it progressed until I received the following message:

```
Making all in src
gmake[2]: Entering directory `/home/peterp/src/coreutils-8.5/src'
gmake  all-am
gmake[3]: Entering directory `/home/peterp/src/coreutils-8.5/src'
  CCLD     chroot
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
eaccess                             ../lib/libcoreutils.a(euidaccess.o)
ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to chroot
```

What could cause this problem?

PS I was only compiling coreutils because I wanted colour `ls`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this post](http://www.mail-archive.com/bug-coreutils@gnu.org/msg18328.html) which implied that there might be a missing `-lgen` parameter required for `libcoreutils.a` to link.

I edited `src/Makefile` and changed the line:

```
LINK = $(CCLD) $(AM_CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(AM_LDFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
```

to:

```
LINK = $(CCLD) $(AM_CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(AM_LDFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -lgen -o $@
```

and running `gmake` again worked through successfully to completion.

Answer (score 1):

You can also compile, (well, install), one individual program if you want. Here's how I just install 'ginstall' on it's own:

```
cd /var/tmp
rm -rf /coreutils coreutils-8.5
untgz /usr/local/src/gnu/coreutils-8.5.tar.gz
cd coreutils-8.5
setenv LDFLAGS -lgen
./configure --prefix=/usr/local \
            --with-libiconv-prefix=/usr/local \
            --with-libintl-prefix=/usr/local
gmake
cd /var/tmp/coreutils-8.5/src
gmake install OPTIONAL_BIN_PROGS="" bin_PROGRAMS=ginstall pkglibdir=""
cd /var/tmp/coreutils-8.5/man
gmake install MAN=install.1
mv /usr/local/bin/install /usr/local/bin/ginstall
mv /usr/local/share/man/man1/install.1 /usr/local/share/man/man1/ginstall.1
```